# How do I read my payslip?

Tags: income-tax, india, salary, job-offer

What will be my in hand salary for the following structure?

```
Basic pay:           15600
GP:                   6000
DA:                   9720
Pension:              1139
EPF:                  1800
Gratuity:             1506
HRA:                  3000
Conveyance allowance: 3741
```

Please answer its urgent. My fixed ctc is 513,672 and total ctc is 1,333,672.

Comment: You haven't even told us what country you're in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compute your self.
Pension, EPF and Gratuity are not directly payable.
So roughly your salary would be 39,000. There would be your contribution to EPF of Rs 1800 and rs 200 as professional taxes. I.e Rs 37,000.
At this salary there is no income tax applicable. So your take home should be around Rs 37,000

Comment: Thank you! Is there any tax for variable ctc?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that variable salary (approx 8.23L) is in the nature of Commission or Bonus or a mix of them. That is taxable.

Tax on Total salary (under new regime) - assuming no 80C, HRA, other deductions - 1.4L
[(source)](https://cleartax.in/paytax/taxcalculator)

Your monthly fixed salary - 5.1L
Variable salary - 8.2L
less Tax - 1.4L
less non cash component of salary - 0.8L (incl. employer + employee contributions)
Total - 11L per annum.

Depending upon how the variable salary is paid, per month cash will change.